# ¿Como puedo eliminar multiples registros en una tabla pivote en Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Soy algo nuevo usando Laravel como framework de desarrollo, y me topé con el problema de cómo eliminar varios registros insertados en la tabla pivote.

Tengo el modelo **Paquetes** y **Producto** y ambos están relacionados con un **Many To Many**, esta relación está en el modelo asi como tambien en la base de datos. La funcionalidad es que el paquete puede tener muchos productos, al momento de agregar datos a la tabla pivote no hay ningún problema, pero al momento de eliminar no se como podría hacerlo.

**Modelo Paquetes**

```
public function productos(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Producto', 'paquete_producto',  
      'paquete_id', 'producto_id')
          ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Modelo Producto**

```
public function paquetes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Paquetes', 'paquete_producto', 
        'paquete_id', 'producto_id')
          ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Para hacer guardar los registros en la tabla pivote uso esto:

```
$paquete->productos()->sync((array)$producto_id);
```

En la tabla pivote es lo que se almacena, y lo quiero es eliminar la relación con los todos id_producto relacionados con un id_paquete de cierto paquete.

[image: tabla pivote paquete_producto]

He estado investigando y tengo entendido que con la función `detach()` se pueden eliminar los registros que están relacionados, lo intenté pero no funciona.

Comment: que es lo que no funcionó? te da un error o solo no lo hace? prueba con `$user->roles()->detach();` cambiando $user por $paquete y roles() por productos()

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias por responder, era un error muy simple que ya solucioné. El método destroy no estaba recibiendo el **id** del paquete a eliminar, simplemente puse un `findOrFail()` e hice lo mismo `$paquetes->productos()->detach()` y funcionó.

Comment: Hola revertí tu edición, pues ni el título debe llevar la leyenda de : **SOLUCIONADO** y la respuesta tampoco va en la pregunta, checa [answer]